# How can I find the optimal solution of quadratic function

Tags: algorithm, minimize, quadratic, maximize

How can I minimize or maximize a quadratic function?
what is the algorithm for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Quadratic formula?

Comment: Set the derivative of the function to zero.

Comment: It's a more general question but for example, X^TAX where A is a matrix, does is there are constrains the algorithm change?

Comment: btw you should ask this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about polynomials of degree in the form

```
y = a·x² + b·x + c
```

There's a very simple, closed solution for that. Take the arithmetic average of the the two roots as given by the general solution

```
x1,2 = (-b +/- sqrt(b² + 4·a·c)) / 2·a
```

That gives you the x value for the min or max.

Take the 2nd derivative of the polynomial to see if its a minimum or a maximum.

All of these have simple closed solution, but this reeks of homework, so I want you do to *something*.